# How to express basic gmake pattern rule in bmake?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake, bmake

I'm trying to emulate this rule with bmake

```
%.o: %.c
    echo $< $@
```

This is valid in GNU make but I'm having a hard time to replicate it with BSD make.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat out of my depth here, but I think there are two things to change:

1. Use suffix rules instead of (unsupported, GNU Make feature) pattern rules.
2. Use the bmake names for automatic variables (bmake supports GNU Make automatic variables but are not recommended)

```
.SUFFIXES: .o
.c.o:
    echo ${.TARGET} ${.IMPSRC}
```

[From netbsd wiki](https://wiki.netbsd.org/projects/project/bsdmake-enhancements/)

> BSD make (aka bmake) uses traditional suffix rules (.c.o: ...) instead of pattern rules like gmake's (%.c:%.o: ...) which are more general and flexible.

See also https://linux.die.net/man/1/bmake

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I also found this resource https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html